# How to get job/run level logs in Databricks?

Tags: log4j, stdout, databricks, stderr, azure-databricks

Databricks only provides cluster level logs in the UI or in the API. Is there a way to configure spark or log4j in databricks such that we get run/job level logs?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a Guide on [Monitoring Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/) on the Azure Architecture Center, explaining the concepts used in this article - [Monitoring And Logging In Azure Databricks With Azure Log Analytics And Grafana](https://cloudarchitected.com/2019/04/monitoring-azure-databricks/).

To provide full data collection, we combine the [Spark monitoring library](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/) with a custom log4j.properties configuration. The build of the monitoring library for Spark 2.4 and the installation in Databricks is automated through the scripts referenced in the tutorial and available at https://github.com/algattik/databricks-monitoring-tutorial/.